# According to Catholicism, would it be allowed for Jews to stone a woman caught in adultery after the scenario in John 8?

Tags: catholicism, morality, adultery

In the Gospel according to John, we can read about the encounter of Jesus with women caught in adultery. Jesus saved the women from being put to death by stoning. Let us suppose that a similar situation happened again the next day, with the difference being that Jesus did not come to rescue.
Would it be moral to stone the women?
**Why**?

Comment: The Jew are still under the Law, at this time. The question deals with Judaism.

Comment: Obviously the Jews are under Roman law at this time. You must edit your question as to whether or not this is a purely Jewish moral question or if they are violating Roman law?  **Would it be moral to stone the women?**

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Catholicism, so I removed that tag.

Comment: I think this has less to do with Catholicism, and more to do with Jewish law. Jewish law states that a woman committing adultery should be stoned, which is part of the encounter with Jesus.

Answer (score 3):

The Jews did not have the right of execution under Roman power. We see this in the case of Jesus himself, whom they wanted to kill but had to go through the process of taking Jesus to Pilate to influence him to carry out the execution.

This is part of the tempting of Christ. Not only do they tempt him with regard to the principle of executing an adulteress (and where was the man, by the way ?) but they are also tempting Jesus in regard to submitting to Roman authority - as they tempted him at another time regarding giving tribute to Caesar when he asked for a coin and told them :

> Render unto Caesar the things that be Caesar's and unto God the things that be God's [Mark 12:17m KJV.]

But the Jews should have accepted the precedent of submitting to a foreign power from, particularly, the Babylonian captivity and from the prophecy, especially, of Jeremiah wherein there is much instruction regarding what sort of attitude Israel should have if God sees fit to humble them with adverse providence and with the chastisement of an occupying force.

Comment: Would it be moral to stone the women, according to Catholicism? This is not a purely legal question, but it does require Catholic sources.

Comment: The header question appeared to me to be different from the body of the question, I was answering the header, 'allowed' being a matter of 'would the Jews be allowed to do it by the Romans ?' Perhaps a little more clarity might be helpful.

Comment: [People need to read past the title?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/people-read-past-the-title)

Comment: @KenGraham Thank you. The accepted answer to that (down-voted) question is very pertinent to my answer and to my, above, comment. Absolutely.

Comment: @KenGraham The alleged interest in the Catholic view point is an afterthought that quite frankly is off topic, and I am not sure that the question is even on topic.  It is asking about Jewish morality in the times that Jesus was alive and doing his ministry.  Nigel, your last paragraph suffers from a run on sentence.  Can you tighten that up a bit?